# One function inside parent function wont run asynchronously

Tags: javascript, async-await

Apologies for being unable to provide working code but, perhaps foolishly, I have a world of functions calling functions and also two calls to an external astar path finder script. I have been moving instances of await, .then and resolve about for days and days now and I just can't get `movePlayer(journeyPart2)` to wait until `await movePlayer(journeyPart1)` has completed. I've watched countless videos about promises as well but I can't see where I'm going wrong. I also tried only returning something once the for loop reaches its last instance but this didn't work. I'm really hoping that it is obvious to someone where I'm going wrong. Unfortunately the second movePlayer function takes a variable amount of time to complete, so I can't use a set interval alone to queue the second movePlayer function.

I don't actually need any data to be returned from the `movePlayer` functions but I understand at least the promise must be returned. How can I make the second `movePlayer` function wait?

Edit: Note that the `else if` works fine as `movePlayer` is only called once.

```
function movePlayer(journey) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < journey.length; i++){
      (function(i){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
          let nextX = journey[i].y;//?SWITCHED X AND Y AS ASTAR SWITCHES IN GRAPH
          let nextY = journey[i].x;//?SWITCHED X AND Y AS ASTAR SWITCHES IN GRAPH
          let fromTop = (26 + (nextX * 16) + (nextY * 16)) + "px";
          let fromLeft = (576 + (nextX * 32) - (nextY * 32)) + "px";
          document.getElementById("playerLayer").style.left = fromLeft;
          document.getElementById("playerLayer").style.top = fromTop;
        }, i * (900));
      }(i));
    }
  resolve("complete")
  reject("failure")
  })
}

function globalPathFindANDMove(cellNumEnd, levelNumEnd) {
  let cellNumStart = playerInfo.cellNow;
  let levelNumStart = playerInfo.levelNow;
  let j1Complete = false;
    if (levelNumStart != levelNumEnd) {
      (async function(){
        try {
          let journeyPart1 = await localPathFind(cellNumStart, undefined, levelNumStart)
          let journeyPart2 = await localPathFind(undefined, cellNumEnd, levelNumEnd)
          let useless = await movePlayer(journeyPart1)
          console.log(useless)
          movePlayer(journeyPart2)//this function won't wait until the function above completes
//------------------------------------------------------changePlayerLevel (levelNumEnd);-----------------------CREATE LATER
        } catch (err) {
        }
      })();
    } else if (levelNumStart == levelNumEnd) {
      let journey = localPathFind(cellNumStart, cellNumEnd, levelNumEnd);
      movePlayer(journey);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Try replacing the self-invoking function and replace it with a normal function. As far as my experience async self invoking functions don't work quite like normal.

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous about `movePlayer`; it will run `setTimeout` `journey.length` times and immediately resolve.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell for sure what you are trying to do in your code, but I think you just want to wait until the `setTimeout` part has run before resolving:

```
function movePlayer(journey) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < journey.length; i++){
      (function(i){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
          let nextX = journey[i].y;//?SWITCHED X AND Y AS ASTAR SWITCHES IN GRAPH
          let nextY = journey[i].x;//?SWITCHED X AND Y AS ASTAR SWITCHES IN GRAPH
          let fromTop = (26 + (nextX * 16) + (nextY * 16)) + "px";
          let fromLeft = (576 + (nextX * 32) - (nextY * 32)) + "px";
          document.getElementById("playerLayer").style.left = fromLeft;
          document.getElementById("playerLayer").style.top = fromTop;
          if (i === journey.length - 1) {
              resolve("complete")
          }
        }, i * (900));
      }(i));
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do. I can't believe I failed to figure this out with all the combinations I tried. Thank you.